# How to change setting to not show the complexity line in visual studio code editor for JavaScript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my Visual Studio Code editor (i use the latest version 1.24.1 now), by default when open any javascript file, there are lot of additional lines showing "Complexity is X, XXX" for example "complexity is 8, it's time to do something" etc..

I didn't install special add-on for such function. It seems this function is brought by default add-ons. 
Does anyone know where to configure a setting NOT to show these annoying messages in editor?

Comment: checked more,  better to use setting "codemetrics.basics.CodeLensEnabled": false"  , the reason is that in the answer to disable all codelens can disable things you don't want to disable.  i just found that the merge conflict codelens is gone and found the issue....

Comment: To use that setting you must install [CodeMetrics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-codemetrics) extension first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's caused by [CodeMetrics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-codemetrics) extension.

Put this setting in your user, workspace or folder settings:

```
"codemetrics.basics.CodeLensEnabled": false,
```

You can get to settings via menu:

> File > Preferences > Settings

or via keyboard shortcut: 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + **<kbd>,</kbd>**

Comment: great, this is the setting! the world is clean now  .  in order to disable to show it, need to change setting to "editor.codeLens": false . please correct the answer so that i can accept it

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you. Sorry if that slowed you down.

Comment: follow up: better to use : "codemetrics.basics.CodeLensEnabled": false

Comment: I was misguided by 'I didn't install special add-on...' part of the question.

Comment: hi all where to put the above settings in VSCode? Can not find it

Answer (score 0):

[CodeMetrics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-codemetrics) is a Visual Studio (VS) Code extension which computes the complexity of your methods (functions) and classes; that is: the levels of nesting within your functions and classes.

Yes! These `Complexity ...` statements are annoying, but they can be very powerful if used smartly. Yes! Your code works perfectly fine even without these `Complexity ...` statements, but there is something known as [Software Quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality#Measurement).

The more complex your functions are, the more difficult it is to maintain the software. Not only does it affect [efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality#Efficiency) and [security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality#Security) of your software, but the increased level of complexities kind of resists you from expanding the software, from taking it to the next level. The more complex your functions, the more inelegant your code is.

**CodeMetrics**, therefore, is an excellent tool to know when is it the right time to [refactor](https://youtu.be/2VFE6nWS3As) your functions if they are becoming too complex, by using a more elegant approach.

Nevertheless, the best practice, in my opinion, is:

1. Go to `Settings` of your VS Code (shortcut: **Ctrl + ,**) and search "CodeMetrics".
2. Click `CodeMetrics configuration` within `Extensions`, and change the second option `Code Lens Hidden Under` *Threshold* to **5** from `3`.
3. Play around with it and set a value (that is not too high otherwise the purpose would die) that suits your programming needs.

This way those `Complexity is ${x} Everything is Cool` would only appear when your functions/classes reach a determined level of complexity - x.

**Remember:** Programming is all about *simplicity* and *elegance*! The more elegant your code is, the more powerful it is.